# iron-session Package path ./next/dist is not exported from package

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm using `iron-session`, and getting this error. Here is my code:

```
import { withIronSessionSsr } from 'iron-session/next/dist';

...


export const getServerSideProps = withIronSessionSsr(async function ({
  req,
  res,
}) {

  // Get id param of dynamic route
  const { id } = req.query;

  return {
    props: { user: req.session.user },
  };
},
ironOptions);
```

This results in the error:

```
./pages/profile/[id].js:14:0
Module not found: Package path ./next/dist is not exported from package /Users/.../.../node_modules/iron-session (see exports field in /Users/.../.../node_modules/iron-session/package.json)
> 14 | import { withIronSessionSsr } from 'iron-session/next/dist';
  15 | 
  16 | export default function Page({ user }) {

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error has to do with a bug in VSCode, which gave an incorrect **import path**.

The correct import is:

`import { withIronSessionSsr } from 'iron-session/next';`